# what does output parameters of lwe estimator stands for?

Tags: key-exchange, post-quantum-cryptography, lwe, ring-lwe, quantum-cryptanalysis

I want to use lwe estimator to find classical and quantum security of my proposed key exchange protocol. On [this](https://bitbucket.org/malb/lwe-estimator/src/master/) website, I want to understand the output of sage code on  lwe estimator given bellow.

> sage: load("estimator.py")
>
> sage: n, alpha, q = Param.Regev(128)
>
> sage: costs = estimate_lwe(n, alpha, q)

The output is

> usvp: rop:  ≈2^57.2,  red:  ≈2^57.2,  δ_0: 1.009214,  β:  101,  d:  349,  m:      220
>
> dec: rop:  ≈2^61.5,  m:      229,  red:  ≈2^61.5,  δ_0: 1.009595,  β:   93,  d:  357,  babai:  ≈2^46.8,  babai_op:  ≈2^61.9,  repeat:      293,  ε: 0.015625
>
> dual: rop:  ≈2^81.4,  m:      376,  red:  ≈2^81.4,  δ_0: 1.008810,  β:  111,  d:  376,  |v|:  736.521,  repeat:  ≈2^19.0,  ε: 0.003906

What is rop, red, δ_0, β, d, m stands for in the output. I search many official documentation of lwe estimator like [this](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/046.pdf) (they give brief description of other parameters like bop in section 7) and [this](https://readthedocs.org/projects/lwe-estimator/downloads/pdf/latest/). But they provide information about input parameters and algorithms used and not about the output parameters. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

- δ_0: the root Hermite factor required
- β: the BKZ block size
- d: the dimension of the lattice being reduced
- m: the number of LWE samples used

Comment: Thanks for replying. Can you please also tell about rop, red, repeat, \epilson and |v|. So, that I will accept your answer.

Comment: Also, please tell the difference between bop and rop? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I want to use lwe estimator too. But same as you, I can't find any explainations about this. So I search the source code.
The most important fuction is `lattice_reduction_cost()` tell you the cost for **lattice_reduction**.

```
def lattice_reduction_cost(cost_model, delta_0, d, B=None):
"""
Return cost dictionary for returning vector of norm` δ_0^d Vol(Λ)^{1/d}` using provided lattice
reduction algorithm.

:param lattice_reduction_estimate:
:param delta_0: root-Hermite factor `δ_0 > 1`
:param d: lattice dimension
:param B: bit-size of entries

"""
beta = betaf(delta_0)
cost = cost_model(beta, d, B)
return Cost([("rop", cost), ("red", cost), ("delta_0", delta_0), ("beta", beta)])
```

And the default **cost_model** is `reduction_default_cost = BKZ.enum`.It's definition is in `class BKZ`.

---

Have you got some explainations about this question? @vivek. Hope the author provides more READMEs to the lwe estimator, thanks.@MartinR.Albrecht

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography. Part of your answer is rather a comment that you cannot make yet due to reputation. Let see how our moderators can handle this.

Comment: @weizhengxing No complete answer. MartinR.Albrecht is creator of this tool, hope he gives some details. But I will you refer you to an article where you get some idea to use LWE estimator. The link of the article is https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/8300634

Comment: @vivek thanks for this

Answer (score 0):

A full description of the parameters is in the  [documentation.](https://lattice-estimator.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_apidoc/estimator.lwe.html). Each parameter is related to a specific attack such as Dual, Primal and so on.

In summary :

rop: Total number of word operations (≈ CPU cycles).

mem: Total amount of memory used by solver (in elements mod q).

red: Number of word operations in lattice reduction.

β: BKZ block size.

ζ: Number of guessed coordinates.

h1: Number of non-zero components among guessed coordinates (if secret distribution is sparse)

prob: Probability of success in guessing.

repetitions: How often we are required to repeat the attack.

d: Lattice dimension.

t: Number of secrets to guess mod 2 (only if fft is True)